# Unable to change Cufon fonts

Tags: cufon

I have a website that uses cufon font in a strange manner(Atleast I have'nt seen this before). I am trying to change these fonts as they are weird. The code written to display just a simple "Stock Products" is as:

```
<h2><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Stock " style="width: 68px; height: 26px; "><canvas width="93" height="29" style="width: 93px; height: 29px; top: -3px; left: -3px; "></canvas><cufontext>Stock </cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Products" style="width: 96px; height: 26px; "><canvas width="116" height="29" style="width: 116px; height: 29px; top: -3px; left: -3px; "></canvas><cufontext>Products</cufontext></cufon></h2>
```

They only include a cufon.js file in the header.

I tried to replace the font like this:

```
<script src="scripts/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="scripts/Adobe_Fan_Heiti_Standard_OpenType_600.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       Cufon.replace('h2','h1','h3','h4');
     </script>
```

This is not working even. The code is too long and the file are too much to edit code manually, everywhere. Kindly suggest some solution.

THANKS in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your cufon syntax doesn't seem to be correct. In the beginning, instead of

```
Cufon.replace('h2','h1','h3','h4');
```

try

```
Cufon.replace('h2');
```

According to Cufon API, to achieve what your code would indicate, you'd have to use:

```
Cufon.replace('h1')('h2')('h3')('h4');
```

Alternatively, if you're using jQuery, or similar JS framework on your site, it could be:

```
Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4');
```

For more information see: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API